# Calculate present value at t=0 for a set C given the present value of all cash flow is equal for all sets at t=1

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

(*Take  = 0 be the current time in this problem)
We consider the following three sets of cashflows:

Set A: It pays 200, 300 and 500 ( dollars) at time 1, time 2 and time 3 respectively.

Set B: It pays 300 and 700 at time 1 and time 3 respectively.

Set C: It pays 2 and 3 (dollars ) at time 2 and time 3 respectively.

It is given that the money grows at an annual effective interest rate  (where  > 0).

Suppose that the present values of these 3 sets of cashflows at time 1 are equal, calculate the present value of set  at time

If the present value of all cash flow is equal at t=1 and $a(n)=(1+i)^n $

$ 200 + \frac{300×a(1)}{a(2)} + \frac{500×a(1)}{a(3)} = 300 + \frac{700×a(1)}{a(3)} $

$\frac{200}{a(2)}-\frac{300}{a(1)}+100=0$

$100(1+i)^2-300(1+i)+200=0$

$i^2-i=0$

$i=1$

To find $X$,

At $t=1$ , present value of all cash flow is same

$300 + \frac{700×a(1)}{a(3)}=2X\frac{a(1)}{a(2)}+3X\frac{a(1)}{a(3)}$

$300 +\frac{700}{(1+i)^2}=2X\frac{(1+i)}{(1+i)^2}+3X\frac{(1+i)}{(1+i)^3}$

Put i=1

$X=345.45454545$

To get the present value of set C  cash flow at t=0

$$\frac{2×X}{a(2)} +\frac {3×X}{a(3)}= 302.272727$$

Is this method correct as im not sure about calculating present value at time t=1 instead of t=0 ( in order to find X and i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of $i=1$ is right. And your equation to evaluate $X$ is right as well. But the result is $X=\frac{1900}{7}\approx271.43$, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=300%20%2B%5Cfrac%7B700%7D%7B%281%2B1%29%5E2%7D%3D2X%5Cfrac%7B%281%2B1%29%7D%7B%281%2B1%29%5E2%7D%2B3X%5Cfrac%7B%281%2B1%29%7D%7B%281%2B1%29%5E3%7D).

Then your next equation is right as well. With the right result from above the term for the present value of set C cash flow at $t=0$

$$2\cdot \frac{1900}{7}\cdot \frac{1}{2^2}+3\cdot \frac{1900}{7}\cdot \frac{1}{2^3}=237.5$$

Comment: Thanks for helping me out and for correcting my mistake.

Comment: It was just a calculation mistake. But you´ve understood the fincance math, which is the crucial point here.